# Quotient rings of polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, finite-fields

I have come across a quite difficult question while I am studying for a test:

> Let $F=\Bbb Z[x]/(7,x^2-3)$. Let $u$ denote the image of $x$ under the canonical epimorphism from $\Bbb Z[x]$ to $F$.
>   A. Show that $F$ is a field. How many elements does it have?
>   B. Find all the elements of the group $\{z\in F\mid z^2+uz+1=0\}$ and express them by using $u$.

Please help me with an answer.

Comment: In B I think it must be "...of the **field** ..." , and not "...of the *group* ..."

Comment: @DonAntonio Unless it's really in the group of units $F^\times$.

Comment: The answers in B form neither a field nor a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question A has been adequatelly handled by others, so I will concentrate on Question B.
The formula for the solutions of a quadratic equation works over any field of characteristic $\neq2$. Thus
$$
z=\frac{-u\pm\sqrt{u^2-4}}2.
$$
Because $u$ is a zero of $x^2-3$, we know that $u^2=3$. Therefore (remember that we are working modulo $7$)
$$u^2-4=-1=27=9\cdot 3=9u^2=(3u)^2.$$
So the solutions of that equation are
$$
z_1=\frac{-u+3u}2=u\qquad\text{and}\qquad z_2=\frac{-u-3u}2=-2u.
$$

Comment: I used here the fact that both $3$ and $-1=2\cdot3$ are quadratic non-residues modulo $7$. Therefore their ratio is a quadratic residue: $2=3^2$. That explains how I knew that $3u$ would serve well in the role of the square root here.

Answer (score 2):

First, we remark that we are basically looking at $(\mathbb{Z}/(7))[x]/(x^2-3)$.

A. Since $f(x)=x^2-3$ has no zeroes in $\mathbb{Z}/(7)$, it is irreducible, so $F$ is a field. Moreover, $F$ is a quadratic field extension of $\mathbb{Z}/(7)$, so $F$ contains $7^2=49$ elements.

B. Does the $|$ mean 'such that' and do you mean 'field' instead of 'group'? Assuming this: Each element in $F$ can be written in the form $z=a+bu$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}/(7)$. Expanding the given expression gives $$z^2+uz+1 = (a+bu)^2+u(a+bu)+1 = 1+ a^2 + u(2ab+a) + u^2(b^2+b). $$
Since we have modded out $f(x)$, we know that $x^2-3=0\in F$, or equivalently that $x^2\equiv 3$, hence $u^2=3$. Using this, we find that
$$z^2+uz+1 = 1+ a^2 + 3b(b+1) + u(2ab+a).$$
If this ever wants to equal $1$, we need
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}a^2+3b(b+1)=0\\a(2b+1)=0.\end{array}\right.$$

Does this help?

Comment: First, thank you for answering. 
Why should we want that it will equal 1 instead of 0?

Comment: O, I seem to have mistaken a 1 and a 0 somewhere. My mistake, sorry. It's still not much work, since $a=0$ or $2b+1=0$ still holds, though.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: understand and justify/prove each of the following steps (hint of hint:isomorphism theorems!):

$$\Bbb Z[x]/\langle\,7\,,\,x^2-3\,\rangle\stackrel\bullet\cong\left(\Bbb Z[x]/\langle 7\rangle\right)/\langle\,x^2-3\,\rangle\cong\Bbb Z_7[x]/\langle\,x^2-3\,\rangle$$

- On the RHS it must be understood the ideal $\;\langle\; (x^2-3)+\overbrace{7\Bbb Z[x]}^{\langle7\rangle\;\text{in}\;\Bbb Z[x]/\langle7\rangle}\;\rangle\;$ , and similarly (but

  not identically!) in the last expression